# How to change a variable and keep the change from a function inside a function

Tags: python, function, variables, replace, global-variables

```
#a test to see how to call and modify a variable by a function inside a function!
test_variable = "Hello __1__ !!, I'm good, How about you!!"

#function 1 to save to variable
def test_function_1():
    global test_variable
    hello = test_variable
    return hello

#function 2 to use the variable through function 1
def test_function_2(test):
    global test_variable
    word = raw_input("Hi, Enter your word\n")
    print
    test = test.replace("__1__", word)
    return test

#See how the function work!
print test_function_2(test_function_1())

#See if the variable changed by the function or not!
print test_variable
```

I can't keep the change to the variable. I try global in every function and it didn't work.

[image: Showing the problem of changing variable from a function inside a function]

Comment: if you have to ask questions like this, you're likely doing it wrong. Consider re-engineering your code.

Comment: What is the point of the first function? You can just use the second function for everything.

Comment: It isn't like that.. I have a project which is complicated and I have to do it like I mention above from a function inside another function to change in the end the variable

Comment: `test = test.replace("__1__", word)` creates a new string with the desired replacement, and binds it to the _local_ name `test`. It doesn't affect the global `test_variable` at all.  BTW, your code will do exactly the same thing if you get rid of those `global` directives, they aren't doing what you think they're doing.

Comment: I think you'll find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder. Also see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) for a shorter, slightly different take on the same topics.

Comment: Thanks all, Now it's clear to me where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remember in python, strings are immutable. So you can't change them. (I am guessing by 'I can't keep the change to a variable', you were expecting the global `test_variable` to change as well.

You are essentially assigning names. This talk is a good place to start to understand some core python concepts:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns

Comment: True, strings are immutable. But the behaviour that Fahad is seeing _isn't_ about mutability (apart from the fact that string methods create a new string since they cannot mutate the original string), it's about how name binding works in Python.

Comment: Thank you all, Great advice from all of you.. I'm grateful. :)